# How to quickly find the code file that a dialog belongs to in visual studio solution

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Im currently working on a very large solution with a few hundred projects. 
Recently we have been working on cleaning up the visual elements ie. Dialog windows created in Winforms.

So QA decide that they found a Dialog which looks messy and have requested some work done. I have found it quite time consuming to find these dialogs in the code.

If i can display the dialog and attach the visual studio debugger is there any way it can tell me what dialogs are being shown and more importantly the code file name?

Comment: So... are the forms not named in a way that you can find them based on the name QA gives you? Then you can either text search or use Ctrl+, to look it up.

Comment: What about the window title of the dialog?  Can you use that in a "find in files" search?

Comment: Unfortunately No. The text is very generic and generally not configured directly on the control but populated via database or config files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) (developed by me, 30-day trial) to quickly find the code that opens a dialog and handles other UI operations.

Comment: Pretty cool program. Ill trial for a while it but it looks like it solves my problem nicely. Two suggestions. 1) Ability to attach to a running process, 2) Ability to enable the window to automatically scroll to the end as new entries are added to the treeview.